# .htaccess URL redirect not working with space

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

```
http://example.com/Richiesta%20Preventivo/index.html
```

### .htaccess code

```
Redirect 301 /Richiesta%20Preventivo/index.html http://example.com/

Redirect 301 /Richiesta Preventivo/index.html http://example.com/
```

Above both the codes is not working. As we can see there is a space between **Richiesta Preventivo** which is creating the problem. The first code is not working and second one leads to 500 internal server error. I want to know how to redirect the URL with space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%20` is not allowed in  a `Redirect` directive unless you double quote the uri string, try

```
Redirect 301 "/Richiesta%20Preventivo/index.html" http://example.com/

Redirect 301 "/Richiesta Preventivo/index.html" http://example.com/
```